# sudo cp with wildcard syntax doesn't do anything in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, file-transfer

I have a directory containing files that are owned by root, from this directory I wish to copy all the files ending with `errorAll` to another directory. My wildcard syntax is correct because performing a `ls -latr *errorAll` shows all the files that I want to copy.

Attempting to copy (as non root level user) using `cp *errorAll ~/Target/` gives me the expected warning of `cp: cannot create regular file /home/tarskin/errorAlls/calibrated_20130903_healthy#1-b_IgA_again_1401_C10.errorAll: Permission denied`, I just added this step to show that the command should be working (in my opinion).

However when I then run it as a root level user using `sudo cp *errorAll ~/Target/` it doesn't give any message or error and just claims it's done within seconds without having actually copied anything.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

**EDIT**

The following information was requested, output of `ls -ld .` is `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3342336 Oct 22 10:09 .` The output of `ls -ld ~/errorAlls/` is `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3342336 Oct 22 10:09 .`.

Adding `-v` to the `cp` command for verbose output doesn't change anything, the command 'finishes' without doing anything.

Comment: Add the output of `ls -ld .` and `ls -ld ~/Target/` to your question.

Comment: Add "-v" to the cp command to see what it is actually doing.

Comment: Why is a subfolder under `tarskin's` home owned by root? `sudo chown tarskin /home/tarskin/errorAlls` and then `cp *errorAll ~/errorAlls`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it recursively

```
sudo cp -r *errorAll ~/Target/
```